# Is SharePoint Foundation 2013 free?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

In our company, we already have a Windows Server 2008 license, a MS SQL server license and a Windows AD users license (CALs).

If we install the SP 2013 foundation, and create and use sites for Document Management system purposes for AD users do we need to pay additional money for the SP 2013 Foundation?

Are there any official Microsoft links available for this information? I found many such related links but I was not able to find any on an Official Microsoft/MSDN site.

Answer (score 5):

SharePoint Foundation 2013 is free, as long as you have a legitimate Windows Server underneath (with CALs).
You can even use a SQL Server Express database if you wanted, but SQL Server is obviously fine.
A lot of customers are using SharePoint Foundation, free of charge. Unfortunately, the free version is discontinued from SharePoint 2016 (most probably to push these customers to Office 365, what a pity!)

Donwload link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42039

Comment: "SharePoint Foundation 2013 is free, as long as you have a legitimate Windows Server underneath (with CALs)". Can you please provide MS Official link where the similar statement is written?

Comment: I'm still looking for it, and cannot find one at the moment...

Comment: appreciate for your efforts, I am also looking, please share if u able to find